# R: How to Create Table of Mean, SD, and n For One-Way ANOVA Data

Tags: r, summary, anova

I have been trying my hardest in order to figure out how to create a summary table of information of Mean, SD, and n for the treatment groups I used when performing one-way ANOVA.

This is what I have:

First, I put my data into R.

```
    Group1 <- c(9,10,7,8,4)
    Group2 <- c(3,5,4,6,2)
    Group3 <- c(4,6,5,3,4)
    Group4 <- c(9,9,6,8,10)
    Group5 <- c(3,3,2,3,4)

    Combined_Groups<-data.frame(cbind(Group1,Group2,Group3,Group4,Group5))
    Combined_Groups #shows spreadsheet like results
    summary((Combined_Groups)) #min, median, mean, max

    Stacked_Groups <- stack(Combined_Groups)
    Stacked_Groups #shows the table Stacked_Groups

    Anova_Results<-aov(values~ind,data=Stacked_Groups)
    summary(Anova_Results) #shows Anova_Results

    qf (.95, df1=4, df2=20) #this gives you the critical mean of the F distribution
```

This is where I run into my issue. I tried a variety of ways to create a table, but they all failed. Also, for some reason n() is not recognized as a function to get number of replicates per treatment group.

What is the correct code to get a table of mean,SD, and n for each treatment group? Also, how to you get n() to be recognized as a function to get number of replicates per treatment group?

Comment: t(apply(Combined_Groups, 2, function(x) c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x), n=length(x))))

Comment: For some reason when I run that code it comes back with this error:       
        Error in apply(Combined_Groups, 2, function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd 
        = sd(x),  : 
        dim(X) must have a positive length

Comment: It sounds like you have a different `Combined_Groups` than the one created in the first 6 lines of your original post.  And I'm guessing this new `Combined_Groups` is a vector instead of a data.frame.  In order for the `t(apply())` command to work, `Combined_Groups` should have two dimensions (rows and columns).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  When I started fresh and I just put in the `Group1 <-....Group5` data and the next line after that, `Combined_Groups<-data`..., and then put in the `t(apply... code` I was able to get a table. So to see where the error came from I put in the rest of  the code; Although, I noted I did not need 2 () around `summary((Combined_Groups))`. Is just this one difference the possible cause for the error? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you other than you had a different `Combined_Groups` than then one created in the first 6 lines of your post.  The remaining lines of your post do not alter `Combined_Groups`.